# Change text value by clicking drop down list - JQuery

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/ZbcVH/1/

HTML

```
<div id="locationselect"><ul><li>United Kingdom</li><li>France</li><li>Germany</li></ul></div>
<input tpye="text" id="location" />
```

Jquery

```
$('#locationselect').click(function() {
    $('#location').html($(this).val());
});
```

As demonstrated in the link above, I basically want to select the value from the unordered list items, **id="locationselect"** and then put the selected list item's value into the **id="location"** text box. I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong.

I'm sure it's something simple. I've tried looking at other questions to help, but it doesn't seem to be clicking.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. In the input, use `val()` to change the value. And get `text()` on your li.

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbcVH/2/)</kbd>

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#locationselect li').click(function() {
        $('#location').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

or with `.on`

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#locationselect li').on('click',function() {
        $('#location').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: This is definitely what I'm looking for, however it doesn't work with my script. It might be worth me adding that, with the input textbox with id="location", the user starts typing their location, a drop down is then populated from a database. Could it be that the scripts are clashing or would that not make a difference? [link]http://jsfiddle.net/ZbcVH/28/ Thanks

Comment: As the user types in their location into the text field **id="location"**, it returns a list from **<div id="locationselect"** of all the locations that start with the locations first letter (eg. "L" would return a list of Leeds, Leister, London) However, when you click on the list option "London", it does not update the input text field? It must be a clash with the id="location" right? =S

Comment: It's because there are no keyup event when you add text with text(). You can [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) keyup like this :  `$('#location').val($(this).text()).keyup();` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbcVH/35/)

Comment: I'm able to return the list of locations as wanted, I just can't seem to click on the populated list item and and have it pop into the text box for auto completion. Gah! Confused! Thanks, for your help though. You've put me on the right lines =) Hopefully I can figure this out

Comment: Glad to help you. I think you have all information to continue. Good luck

Comment: Please close the subject if you think there is good answer. Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

You need [.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of .val to retrieve the value, [.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of .html to set the value, and you need to bind onto the `li` instead of the parent `div`:

```
$('#locationselect li').click(function() {
    $('#location').val($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the listener on the `li` element itself and then fetch the `text` from that.

Try this solution:

```
<div id="locationselect"><ul><li>United Kingdom</li><li>France</li><li>Germany</li></ul></div>
<input tpye="text" id="location" />

$('#locationselect li').click(function() {
    $('#location').val($(this).text());
});
```

See updated **JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/WYUSn/

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from http://jsfiddle.net/ZbcVH/8/ there were two mein errors:

You need to use `li` instead of `#locationselect` and you should use `.text()` instead of `.val()`.