# Jquery Autocomplete text field problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

This is a follow on from [this thread(change text value by clicking drop down list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633307/change-text-value-by-clicking-drop-down-list-jquery)
Where this problem was solved it did not work with my script so I'm going to go more in depth.

HTML

```
<li><input type="text" id="location"></li>
<div id="locationselect"></div>
```

User starts typing in their location into **text input id="location"**, AJAX is used to return a list of locations that start with user input. (eg. "Lon" would return London, Long Eaton etc and returns results to  as an unordered list)

[JQuery/AJAX Code](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbcVH/44/)

getlocations.php

```
<?php

    if ($location == '') {echo "";}
    else {
        echo "<ul>";
        while($location = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<li>". $location['location'] ."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
```

**THIS ALL WORKS GREAT!!!** I get the dropdown of the locations as user input is typed, so the AJAX part is working.

The problem I am having now is that ...
It brings up a list of the locations as you type the letters HOWEVER

```
$('#locationselect li').click(function() {
    $('#location').val($(this).text());
});
```

Does not seem to autocomplete the **id="location" input text field** when a list item is clicked. Is there something missing from the getlocations.php file?

Really Confused by this, apologies for a new thread but the last was technically answered =) Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly than you are binding the click event to any li under #locationselect before any are available.
You should bind the click event after the li elements are loaded and rendered in the ajax call. Try this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#location').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#location').length == 0) {
        $('#locationselect').hide();
    }
    $('#locationselect').html("");
    var location = $('#location').val();
    location = $.trim(location);
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"getlocations.php",
        data:"location="+location,
        success:function(data){
            $("#locationselect").html(data);
            $('#locationselect li').click(function() {
                $('#location').val($(this).text());
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: YOU ABSOLUTE LEGEND! Yes this has worked exactly as intended! I thought doing it that way WOULD bind it after the event. Thank you very much =) I just need to remove the list items once user has clicked. I shall give it ago myself, if it doesn't work, i'll be coming to you hah